# Keep the same file name on output file on a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm currently working on an encrypting/decrypting automatization project and I need to create batch files for the task scheduler

And I'm facing the issue with the decrypting command

```
 --passphrase "password" --batch -d --output ".JOAARPT.out" "*.JOAARPT"
```

the command decrypts all the JOAARPT files and changes the output file to JOAARPT.out but I cannot make the created decrypted file keep the same name as the source file

What wildcard should I use?

Comment: What is the decryption command? you just specified its arguments…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cmd.exe` a `FOR` loop is needed. Yes, it is awkward, but it is what it is. Use the `FOR /?` command to learn all about it.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /B "*.JOAARPT"') DO (
    decry.exe --passphrase "password" --batch -d --output "%%~nA.JOAARPT.out" "%%~A"
)
```

If you wanted to step up to PowerShell, you could:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter "*.JOAARPT" |
    ForEach-Object {
        & decry.exe --passphrase "password" --batch -d --output $($_.BaseName + '.JOAARPT.out') "$_.FullName"
    }
```